# How using bower would improve the first download of my webpage

Tags: angularjs, performance, frontend, bower

I´m trying to understand and figure out the best approach when adding the references of external front end libraries like bootstrap,angularjs,ui-router,etc on my index.html file from my SPA and angularJS-based application. The reason behind it, is that on the first download from the client side, it really takes to long and even longer when there is a bad internet connection.

So far, I know that the existing methods for achieving the same goal are the following:

1. **Deploying downloaded libraries to the server**: Download the libraries to a folder inside my project and reference them from my **index.html** file. Then, they will go to the production server and be downloaded the first time the webpage is opened.
2. **Referencing the libraries hosted in the cloud or a (Content Delivery Network) CDN**.I know that doing this process just means referencing the files (if they are available on a CDN) by adding the url instead of the route from the library inside my project. I assume it would help me saving space on my server but, ***would it help me speed up the download on the first time the SPA is accessed?***
3. **Using a front end package manager(bower)**: I understand that when I add a library, I have the possibility to setup a bower.json file, which references all my front end libraries. It takes to run the command `bower install` so that the reference appears in the bower.json. Then, by doing so and according to this [Manage your Frontend Dependencies with Bower](https://zellwk.com/blog/bower/) it states that I´m able to control the versions from the libraries, install them and even changing the file or directory where the files will be downloaded when you install them. ***Would I be able to speed up the download from the client side of the application or this  would be just useful for avoiding a heavy download when cloning a repo?***

I´m not sure if the optimization of this **referencing process**, would really help me improve the performance of my page and rather should be thinking about the compression of the files or something like that.

I will really appreciate any advice and help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hosting the libraries from your own server can be slow depending on how well your server is distributed. If you are using a service like Amazon EC2, it will not be a problem, since Amazon has a huge world-wide network. However, if you are physically running your own server, users that are in a distant part of the world would experience slow downloads.
2. CDN's are fast because they are usually well-distributed. The downside is that if the CDN goes down (fairly rare), so does your SPA.
3. Bower does absolutely nothing to improve the speed of library downloads. It is simply a convenient, organizational tool to track the versions of libraries you use in your project.

> I'm not sure if the optimization of this referencing process, would
>   really help me improve the performance of my page and rather should be
>   thinking about the compression of the files or something like that.

This is correct. If you are hosting your own files, you should make sure you are compressing the libraries for faster downloading. Keep in mind that although compression makes the file size smaller for faster downloading, there will be a slight delay while your browser unzips the compressed file.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that option 1 is a no-go because it would become really hard to manage and make the application difficult to port.

As for option 2, that would theoretically improve the download speed because the purpose of CDNs is to provide close network download paths for the client e.g. a user in India would download from a CDN in India as opposed to downloading from your server in e.g. Canada. That being said, it's also not optimal because it relies on multiple HTTP requests, if one fails because of internet connection, the whole app is affected.

Option 3 I believe is best, because as you mention it provides portability of application as well as good version control. Another key benefit is that you can preprocess all your library code using Grunt/Webpack/etc. by downloading all the dependencies at build time, minifying, uglyfing and concatenating all library code into one file e.g. vendor.js, thus reducing the number of HTTP request to only one and serving that code in the most compressed format. There are further optimisations available as well, such as gzip, pushing your whole vendor.js on a CDN, caching, pre-fetching and many more I'm sure.